# Metamask Error messages shows only revert

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, error

I have a little problem with the error messages I receive from MetaMask. In my dApp I have a modifiers which should throw an error with an error message. However, in MetaMask I only receive the RPC error message:
`"{code: -32603, message: "Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {…VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"}"`

Is it possible to extract the error in some other way?
Also, could that be linked to the usage of inheritance? 
Because the modifiers are in a separate contract.
To my knowledge, after compilation there should only be one contract (even if inheritance was used).

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is a known metamask limitation, you could always write on this issue so it gets revisited by the team. As far as i could tell there was not a way to extract the error.

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/4559

(Disclaimer: I submitted this issue almost a year ago)